# postgres syntax error in sql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

```
    select * from (
    select max(h.updated_datetime) as max, min(h.updated_datetime) as min from report r, report_history h, procedure_runtime_information PRI, study S
    where 
    h.report_fk=r.pk and
    r.study_fk=S.pk and
    PRI.pk=S.procedure_runtime_fk and
    extract(epoch from (max(h.updated_datetime) - min(h.updated_datetime) ) <=900 and
    h.pk IN (
    select pk from 
    (select * from report_history where report_fk=r.pk) as result
    )

  and r.status_fk =21 group by r.pk)as result1;
```

this is my query i have a syntax error can any one help me fix this 
thanks in advance

Comment: Downvoted because you left out pretty key info like **the error message**. Please read the asking better questions section of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't bother telling us what the error is I have to guess, that it's this line:

```
AND h.pk IN (SELECT pk FROM (SELECT * FROM report_history WHERE report_fk=r.pk) AS RESULT)
```

The nesting level for the where condition is "too deep" and I think it cannot see the `r` alias in the where clause.

But the nested select is totally useless in your case anyway, so you can rewrite that condition as:

```
AND h.pk IN (SELECT pk FROM report_history WHERE report_fk=r.pk)
```

Even if that doesn't solve your problem, it makes your query more readable.

Then you are using an aggregate in the `where` clause which is also not allowed, you have to move it to a having clause.

```
having extract(epoch from (max(h.updated_datetime) - min(h.updated_datetime))) <=900
```

The `having` clause comes *after* the `group by`

You were also missing a closing `)` but that is hard to tell because of your formatting (which I find *very* hard to read)

---

You should also get used to explicit `JOIN` syntax. The implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause are error-prone and no longer recommended.